# R xts package - to.period by minute over a day

Tags: r, xts

I have a minute timeseries in xts. I am wondering if there is an elegant way to get OHLC from the start of the day until each minute of my time series. Eg for the minute 2017-07-14 12:29 I will have the open of 2017-07-14 08:00, the close of 2017-07-14 12:29 and the min/max during the period 2017-07-14 08:00 until 2017-07-14 12:29.
My time serie is fully filled from 08:00 to 22:00 (841 minute points).
I am thinking about doing a loop but I guess there is a more elegant way.

Thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate cumulative max/min using `cummax()` and `cummin()`, respectively.  You just need to apply those functions by day.  You can do that by `split()`ing your data into daily groups, applying the function below to each group, then `rbind()`ing the data back together.

Here's a reproducible example using daily data in the xts package.

```
library(xts)
set.seed(21)
tm <- timeBasedSeq('2017-07-14/2017-07-15/M')
x <- xts(20*cumprod(1+rnorm(length(tm), 0, 0.0025)), tm)
colnames(x) <- "price"

aggfun <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(ncol(x) > 0)
  # remove potential column name
  colnames(x) <- NULL
  r <- xts(cbind(Open = rep(x[1], nrow(x)),
                 High = cummax(x),
                 Low = cummin(x),
                 Close = x), index(x))
  r
}
y <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, "day"), aggfun))
```

The output from one day to the next looks like:

```
y[1439:1442]
#                         Open     High      Low    Close
# 2017-07-14 23:58:00 20.03965 25.02193 19.60128 23.73810
# 2017-07-14 23:59:00 20.03965 25.02193 19.60128 23.71598
# 2017-07-15 00:00:00 23.73816 23.73816 23.73816 23.73816
# 2017-07-15 00:01:00 23.73816 23.73816 23.71164 23.71164
```

Comment: Many thanks. There is a small typo: days instead of day in the split function.